# Android Activity has been destroyed when called getChildFragmentManager...commit()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My application structure is like this:

- ActivityMedia is main activity that has 2 tabs: Photo & Video, each tab is FragmentCategory.

In each tab, the 1st screen is list of Category, and when click on a category, will show FragmentMediaList, which is list of Media for the category, with this code:

```
((ActivityMedia) getActivity()).addFragment(FragmentMediaList.newInstance(mediaType, aSite, null));
```

- When clicking back from FragmentMediaList of Photo, it will show FragmentCategory of Photo, same for Video tab
- In FragmentMediaList, when click on an item, will show ActivityMediaPlayer with this code:

  ```
  Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityMediaPlayer.class);
  getActivity().startActivity(it);
  ```
- When clicking back from ActivityMediaPlayer, app will show FragmentMediaList , back again, will show FragmentCategory

Everything was fine when I tested on my device, but on some of user's devices, when starting ActivityMediaPlayer, the ActivityMedia seems to be destroyed. When click back from ActivityMediaPlayer, the FragmentMediaList  is showed, click back again, FragmentCategory is showed, but when click on a category in FragmentCategory, crash happens in this line of code of HostFragment class:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

It said "Activity has been destroyed"

Here are my classes details:

ActivityMedia:

```
public class ActivityMedia extends BaseActivity
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

    customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    // increase this limit if you have more tabs!
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    ...
    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!BackStackFragment.handleBackPressed(getSupportFragmentManager())){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

CustomPagerAdapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("VIDEO");
    add("PHOTO");
}};


private List<Fragment> tabs = new ArrayList<>();

public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    initializeTabs();
}

public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Fragment fragment1, Fragment fragment2) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    tabs.add(fragment1);
    tabs.add(fragment2);
}

private void initializeTabs() {
    tabs.add(HostFragment.newInstance(FragmentSite.newInstance(MediaType.Movie)));
    tabs.add(HostFragment.newInstance(FragmentSite.newInstance(MediaType.Photo)));
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return tabs.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles.get(position);

 }
}
```

HostFragment:

```
public class HostFragment extends BackStackFragment {
private Fragment fragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.host_fragment, container, false);
    if (fragment != null) {
        replaceFragment(fragment, false);
    }
    return view;
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    try{
        if (addToBackstack) {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).commit();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);
        K.log("Error when commit fragment: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}

public static HostFragment newInstance(Fragment fragment) {
    HostFragment hostFragment = new HostFragment();
    hostFragment.fragment = fragment;
    return hostFragment;
 }
}
```

BackStackFragment:

```
public abstract class BackStackFragment extends BaseFragment {
public static boolean handleBackPressed(FragmentManager fm)
{
    if(fm.getFragments() != null){
        for(Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()){
            if(frag != null && frag.isVisible() && frag instanceof BackStackFragment){
                if(((BackStackFragment)frag).onBackPressed()){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

protected boolean onBackPressed()
{
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    if(handleBackPressed(fm)){
        return true;
    } else if(getUserVisibleHint() && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fm.popBackStack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: handleBackPressed  is calling onBackPressed and onBackPressed calling handleBackPressed, I believe when u tap back due to this fragment popup twice and return false. which made Activity to finish.

Comment: but the fragment is still there, why?